# error on installing passenger nginx module on ubuntu with ruby 2.0.0 via rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, passenger

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS, ruby 2.0 with RVM

during installation. this error occurs.

```
checking for alloca.h... *** /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.10/ext/ruby/extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.10/ext/ruby
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:430:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:561:in `try_cpp'
from /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1040:in `block in have_header'
from /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:in `block in checking_for'
from /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
from /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `block in postpone'
from /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:306:in `open'
from /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:332:in `postpone'
from /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:890:in `checking_for'
from /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1039:in `have_header'
from /home/pastelcorp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.10/ext/ruby/extconf.rb:37:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [cd 'buildout/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux/...]
/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.10/build/ruby_extension.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => nginx => buildout/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux//passenger_native_support.so => buildout/ruby/ruby-2.0.0-x86_64-linux//Makefile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It's saying that I must install development tools first.
but I already have done `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

and Here's my mkmf.log file(which I didn't understand at all)

```
" -o conftest -I/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/x86_64-linux -I/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.10/ext/ruby     -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC -g conftest.c  -L. -L/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib -Wl,-R/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     '-Wl,-rpath,/../lib' -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib -L/home/pastelcorp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib -lruby   -lpthread"
sh: 1: -o: not found
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Problem solved.

in RVM, I installed ruby2.0.0 with binary, not compiling source.

so I did

`rvm remove 2.0.0` and `rvm install 2.0.0 ----disable-binary`

so ruby 2.0.0 has been compiled from source and passenger compiling works fine.

Comment: `--disable-binary` with only 2 dashes.

Comment: same deal with Ubuntu 14.10, RVM 1.26.11 and Ruby 2.2.3, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

`You have to install development tools first.`

Most likely you're missing some libraries just like the error is indicating. I ran into the same thing a couple weeks back. Here is a nice tutorial similar to the one that helped me out.

http://alexpearce.me/2012/06/setting-up-a-vps/

With a little bit of luck, I believe that this line will solve your current issues, but be sure to look over the whole document.

```
sudo apt-get -y install curl git-core python-software-properties build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-gplv2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Also: I've also always had troubles when using rvm and have found that rbenv works with less hiccups, which is actually mentioned in this tutorial.

For databases, if you aren't using postgres then you should be able to just swap out the bits on database for the mysql equivalent libraries.

Comment: problem solved! check my own answer. and I already has installed all package you mentioned.